# Using watir-webdriver with chrome - can't locate input field?

Tags: ruby, html, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

I have the following HTML:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
```

And I am trying to retrieve this element with the following code:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto('localhost:3000')
puts b.input(:name => "email").exists?
```

This returns `false`, but is most definitely true. I have also tried using `b.text_field(:name => 'email').exists?`, but it returns `false` as well.

The end goal is to change the text of the input, but I can't even locate the element right now. The page loads fine, and after loading it outputs `false`.

Comment: That snippet works for locally.  Any chance the normal cast of characters could be causing the issue (e.g. element is in frame, need to chain the .when_present method because the element hasn't finished loading, etc.)?

Comment: @orde That was the issue indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your code is actually being executed before the element is finished loading. You need to chain a few methods (namely `.when_present` and `.exists?` to ensure your element is loaded before attempting to check it's existence:

```
puts b.input(:name => "email").when_present.exists?
```

Good luck!